Ratio between convex combinations
I have a (well-defined) ratio $r$ between convex combinations of scalars $x_i$ and $y_i$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 r = \dfrac{y}{x} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i x_i}{\sum^k_{i=1} \lambda_i y_i},
\end{equation}
where $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ and $\lambda_i \geq 0$. In addition, I'm assuming that $x_i \neq 0$, $y_i \neq 0$, $\forall i$.
I would like to derive (if it exists) a set of rational functions $f_{ij}(x_i,y_j)$ such that $r$ can also be written as a convex combination of the $f_{ij}$, that is
\begin{equation}
r = \sum_{ i,j =1}^{\bar{k}_1, \bar{k}_2} \overline{\lambda_{ij}} f_{ij}(x_i, y_j),
\end{equation}
with $\sum_{ij} \overline{\lambda_{ij}} = 1$ and $\overline{\lambda_{ij}} \geq 0$, and possibly $\overline{k}_1 + \overline{k}_2 \geq k$.
I have tried, for instance, all possible combinations of the ratios between the $x_i$ and $y_j$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
r \overset{?}{=}  \sum_{{i,j}=1}^{k,k} \overline{\lambda_{ij}} \dfrac{x_i}{y_j},
\end{equation}
but got automatically stuck.
Is there a systematic way to compute the $f_{ij}$? Thanks!
Edit:
Attempt with $k = 2$:
\begin{equation}
r = \dfrac{\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2}{\lambda_1 y_1 + \lambda_2 y_2} \overset{?}{=} \overline{\lambda_{11}}\dfrac{x_1}{y_1} + \overline{\lambda_{12}}\dfrac{x_1}{y_2} + \overline{\lambda_{21}}\dfrac{x_2}{y_1} + \overline{\lambda_{22}}\dfrac{x_2}{y_2}. 
\end{equation}
Writing $\overline{\lambda_{ij}} = \dfrac{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}}$, and equating for the denominator I find that:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 y_1 + \lambda_2 y_2 = ((b_{11}+b_{21}) y_1)((b_{12}+b_{22}) y_2),
\end{equation}
which seem to imply that the $b_{ij}$ need to be functions of $(x_i,y_j)$ as well as of the $\lambda_i$, and hence the choice of $f_{ij}$ might not be suitable.

Have you tried to solve your problem for $k=2$? [edit] the question to show us your worl in that case.

Just added the case for $k=2$, with the "candidate" $f_{ij}$.

The $\bar{\lambda_{i,j}}$ are just real numbers. Why do you write them as fractions with denominators that have an independent meaning?

Thanks for the quick response. I thought it was easier to show how each $\overline{\lambda_{ij}}$ can "affect" the denominator directly.  This was done without any loss of generality. I, unfortunately, arrive at the same conclusions by using $\overline{\lambda_{ij}}$ without splitting in $a$'s and $b$'s.

Your work suggests that what you hope to do is impossible (which is what I suspected from the start). You might be able to show that by seeing what the extreme cases (some $\lambda$'s or $x$'s equal to $0$) force about the hypotheical functions $f_{i,j}$

We only need to consider the case $k=2$, because we can write $x$ and $y$ as convex combinations of maximal/minimal values of these $x_i,y_i$.
Then
$$
r = \frac{ \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 } { \lambda' y_1 + (1-\lambda') y_2}
$$
with $x_1 \le x_2$, $y_1 \le y_2$ and $ \lambda,\lambda'\in [0,1]$.
Let me assume that $0<y_1<y_2$, otherwise the denominator might be zero in some cases.
Then
$$
r \le \frac{ x_2 } { \lambda' y_1 + (1-\lambda') y_2} \le \frac{ x_2 } { y_1}
$$
and
$$
r \ge \frac{ x_1 } { \lambda' y_1 + (1-\lambda') y_2} \le \frac{ x_1 } { y_2}.
$$
Hence with
$$
r = \lambda'' \frac{ x_2 } { y_1} + (1-\lambda'') \frac{ x_1 } { y_2}
$$
you have the desired decomposition into rational functions.

Many thanks for your input! The idea of bounding the sum is very clever. Do you think a similar argument (in absolute value) can be used if the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are complex valued ?
